# how can I get the binaries of python file for mips

Tags: python, mips, binaryfiles

I have the source code of a program written in python and I want to get the binaries of this program for the MIPS architecture. How can I do this?

Comment: Python is an interpreted language, there are no binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Although indeed Python is interpreted,rather than compiled, I think this may answer the question behind your question:

https://python-mips.blogspot.nl

and

https://www.cnx-software.com/2011/02/04/cross-compiling-python-for-mips-and-arm-platforms.